# C language_Error:expected ')' before ';' token

Tags: c, token

Just in case you need to know what the program I'm working on -It's a homework question:A five-digit number is entered through the keyboard. Write a function to obtain the reversed number and another function to determine whether the original and reversed numbers are equal or not. Use this functions inside the main() and provide the necessary arguments to get a result.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Reversed(int rev);
int Equality(int equ);

int main (){
    int num,result;
    printf("Please enter a number that has five digits:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    result=Equality(num);
    return 0;
}

int Reversed(int num){
int number=num;
int rev=0;
int digit;
do{ 
    digit=num%10;
    rev=rev*10+digit;
    num=num/10;
}
while  ((num>0)); 
return rev; 
}

int Equality(num){
    int reve,numb;
    if ( (numb=num)== (reve=Reversed(num);) )
printf("number equals the reversed number");
else 
printf("number doesn't equal the reversed number");
}
```

Comment: check this line `f ( (numb=num)== (reve=Reversed(num);) )`

Comment: That's true, it's the line that has the mistake but I don't know how to correct it..

Comment: Why did you not tell us which line had the mistake?

Comment: Just remove the semicolon.

Comment: Simply remove the `;` in the line

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: But I'm calling a function.. will it work if i removed ; ?

Comment: Yes, of course because `;` is by no means part of function call operator in C. Try it.

Comment: @MartinJames sorry..

Comment: Note that `Equality()` have no `return` statement, so if you use value of `result` in the `main()` function, you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Wow Thanks @MikeCAT and lan it really worked! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some points to fix:

- Remove semicolon in `if ( (numb=num)== (reve=Reversed(num);) )`, which is not ought to be. ( the main problem)
- Format your code properly.
- `Equality()` doesn't have `return` statement, so what it returns is not usable.
- I guess `Equality()` is supposed to only determine that, not to print the result.
- The variables `reve` and `numb` in `Equality()`, and `number` in `Reversed()` are not used other than being assigned, so you won't need them.
- Type of function arguments shouldn't be omitted.

corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Reversed(int rev);
int Equality(int equ);

int main (void){
    int num;
    printf("Please enter a number that has five digits:");
    if(scanf("%d", &num) != 1){
        puts("read error");
        return 1;
    }
    if(Equality(num))
        printf("number equals the reversed number");
    else 
        printf("number doesn't equal the reversed number");
    return 0;
}

int Reversed(int num){
    int rev=0;
    int digit;
    do{ 
        digit=num%10;
        rev=rev*10+digit;
        num=num/10;
    }
    while (num>0); 
    return rev;
}

int Equality(int num){
    return ( num == Reversed(num) );
}
```